# Github actions triggers the wrong workflow as status checks on PR creation

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows. They have the following:

1. my-prod-ci

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  myjob:
```

2. my-dev-ci

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  myjob:
```

The status checks in the repo is set to use `myjob`

When I create a PR from `feature` branch to `develop` branch, both the workflows are run. I only want `my-dev-ci` to run.
Similarly on creating a PR from `develop` to `master` branch, both workflows are run. I only want `my-prod-ci` to run.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the [GitHub workflow syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-ignoring-branches-and-tags), I would try and add explicit `branches` pattern directives:

Example:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - 'master'
    - '!feature'
jobs:
  myjob:
```

Comment: Looks like I can't do this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#excluding-branches-and-tags

Comment: @kosta I agree. Would branches patterns work better? See my edited answer.